# Check if value exists from a datatable to another datatable with LIKE operator

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I decided to write this in VB.NET to brush up on my knowledge.  I have 2 Datatables and each one has a different number of columns.

> Datatable1 = 20 columns
>
> Datatable2 = 10 columns

I want to check if a given value from Datatable1 exists in Datatable2.  The "like" operator will need to be used because the value in Datatable2 will contain the specific value from Datatable1.  Example below with fewer columns to demonstrate.

```
DataTable1 - Call this ADT1
Column 1 | Column 2| Column 3
------------------------------
A        | B       | C

DataTable2 - Call this BDT1
Column 1 | Column 2
A        | 123C456
```

I tried to used LINQ, but I cannot seem to get the syntax correct.  This is what I have tried.

```
Dim results = From ADT2 In ADT1
              Where (From BDT2 In BDT1 Where BDT2(2).Contains(ADT2(3))).ToString
              Select ADT2
```

Error message:  Conversion from string "System.Data.EnumerableRowCollect" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

The expected result should match Column 3 value of "C" from Datatable1 to Column 2 value of "123C456" from Datatable2.  How do I fix the conversion error?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition specified in a `Where` clause must evaluate to a `Booelan`.  In your case, your condition is a query that returns a list of rows, which is not a `Boolean`.  What you care about is whether that list has any items, which is what the `Any` method is for:

```
Where (From BDT2 In BDT1 Where BDT2(2).Contains(ADT2(3))).Any()
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance!  This did eliminate the error message that I received.  I have another question though.  I expected my query to return 1 result, but it did not.  Did it evaluate it correctly?  It returned 0 results.

Comment: Disregard the last message.  I had to change my date condition.  It all works.  Thanks again!